# Why my global variable is not accessible within a function?

Tags: javascript

I thought that `myColor` would be accessible from `sayColor()` local context but it isn't even though I'm declaring myColor after the first alert. Why?

```
var myColor = "blue";
function sayColor() {
    alert(myColor); //undefined expected blue
    var myColor = "green";
    alert(myColor); //green
}
sayColor();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's going on here is called "hoisting". Variable declarations that use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and function statements are "hoisted" to the top of their containing scope. (Note that, from ES6 on, [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) have different semantics.) So, to the browser's mind, your code actually looks like this:

```
var myColor = "blue";
function sayColor() {
    var myColor;
    alert(myColor); //undefined expected blue
    myColor = "green";
    alert(myColor); //green
}
sayColor();
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet):

> Every definition of a variable is really a declaration of the variable at the top of its scope and an assignment at the place where the definition is.

Comment: This is ... not intuitive or useful.  Why have they not fixed this yet?  I would expect the variable to be declared at the spot in the code where the variable is declared.

Answer (score 7):

You are hiding the global variable `myColor` with a local variable of the same name. Remove the `var` keyword from within the function to see the global variable.

```
var myColor = "blue";
function sayColor() {
    alert(myColor);
    myColor = "green"; // Omit the "var" keyword.
    alert(myColor);
}
sayColor();
```

Javascript only has function scope, and all variables declared within a function are hoisted to the top so they are available throughout the function. The first alert in the OP's original version was using the uninitialized, hoisted, local variable, which is why it printed `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't be available in the first alert because it isn't declared yet?

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio No, that's not how functions work in JavaScript. Variables are visible throughout the entire function in which they are declared.

Comment: The variable declaration is *hoisted* to the top of the function. It is effectively: `function sayColor(){ var myColor; alert(myColor); myColor = "green"; alert(myColor); }`

Comment: @NagaJolokia Indeed it does now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable inside the function again. The browser is reading the function before the assignment and this causes the undefined result.

Its correct.

```
var myColor = "blue";
function sayColor() {
    alert(myColor); //undefined expected blue
    myColor = "green";
    alert(myColor); //green
}
sayColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring it again.

```
 var myColor = "green";
```

In JavaScript before a function is executed by the interpreter, it scans the entire function for `var ...` statements. So that is why your myColor variable is reset even before the first statement of your function is executed.