# Why doesn't document.getElementById() work in svelte?

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte

In order to be able to style a File-Upload Button in HTML (technically file input), I need to pass on the buttons click event to the file input. The following code tries to does exactly that. My code is nearly identical to the one found on [MDN Webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/file/using_files_from_web_applications). So why doesn't fileInput.click() work, whilst document.getElementById(fileElem).click() does?

```
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileElem");

  function passDownClick(e) {
    console.log("I was clicked 1");
    console.log(fileInput);
    console.log(document.getElementById("fileElem"));
    fileInput.click();
    document.getElementById("fileElem").click();
  }
</script>

<input
  type="file"
  id="fileElem"
  multiple
  accept="image/*"
  style="display:none"
/>
<button id="fileSelect" on:click={passDownClick}>Select some files</button>
```

Here you can see the console, after the button is clicked once.

```
client.ts:352 [vite] hot updated: /src/lib/UploadButton.svelte
UploadButton.svelte:5 I was clicked 1
UploadButton.svelte:6 null
UploadButton.svelte:7 <input type=​"file" id=​"fileElem" multiple accept=​"image/​*" style=​"display:​ none;​">​
```

I have prepared a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/07970d7e80124775b13f552dfee443fa?version=3.46.6) so you can easily check out the code, without having to deal with any setup.

Comment: Just Put The `const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileElem");` inside the function and it will work as you expected.

Comment: @mrtechtroid Why is this the case?

Comment: Read This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494071/why-my-global-variable-is-not-accessible-within-a-function

Comment: @mrtechtroid Does that mean, that a function does not know any variable if they are not a parameter or declared globally?

Comment: @mrtechtroid Then should I pass the variable as a parameter, make it global or declare it in every function seperatly?

Comment: I believe this was closed too early as the linked duplicate is not entirely the same.  The issue here is that your line `fileInput = ...` runs _before_ the DOM was created, so fileInput will be undefined, that is why you cannot use the click function on it.

Comment: Have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4e6e0aee66f4fbd911eb46f00f2e05c?version=3.46.6) ~ and [this article](https://geoffrich.net/posts/clean-component-tips/#heading-work-with-the-component-template-not-against-it) might be of interest

Comment: When you use `getElementById` in svelte, you know you are not doing it the right way :)